# Objective-C form framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, forms, verification

I'm thinking is there any 3rd party framework that allows to easily create, verify forms in Objective-C?
This is a task we developers do very often and I believe this is on of the most difficult and long part to code.

Each time I've to take care about the TextFields, displaying the proper width of label and textfield in the tableview's cells or any other views. Implementing the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to allow entering only digits, or certain strings. When it comes to digits and currency, we have to deal in displaying the number correctly to the user (number formatter) and sending the float or double value to the API or Core Data. We have to check all the values and display popups to notify the user that he hasn't filled one of the textfields or filled it wrong and to focus that field...

What is even more annoying if we have a tableview with a lot of cells with the same cell's identifier, we have to retain all strings and assign them in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so if the user scrolls the table strings are not mixed of removed. Also adding the "next" on the keyboard or previous using the inputaccessoryview to go to the next and previous field.

So is there any framework, collection of class that would allow to simplify it, do you do the same thing over and over again or have nice solutions?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an extremely well written, actively maintained and documented form framework which is open-source

[IBAForms](https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms)

And here's [a little introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/seanwoodhouse/ibaforms) from the framework developers.

Answer (score -7):

There are 3 types of framework in iphone (default)

1. Foundation framework
2. UIkit framework
3. CoreGraphics framework

There are many other types of framework that we can use it as per our requirement.

Comment: Do you have some kind of insight to share as to how the OP can create and verify forms using these three frameworks?